# How do you use parse for timestamp data?

Tags: java, parsing, constructor, timestamp, delimiter

I need to be able to print Flow Sample data in tab-delimited lines of text where each data field is separated by tabs. Using the tab-delimited lines I need to be able to type data in like:

```
Please enter the line of tab-separated data:
USGS    13206000    2021-12-30 14:30    MST 226 P
```

and have it printed out like:

```
---------------------
|     Data Entry    |
---------------------
Please enter the line of tab separated data:
USGS    13206000    2021-12-30 14:30    MST 226 P

---------------------
| Data Confirmation |
---------------------
You entered the following: 
Agency: USGS
Site Number: 13206000
Local Timestamp: Thu 30 Dec 2021 02:30:00 PM MST
UTC Timestamp: Thu 30 Dec 2021 09:30:00 PM UTC
Flow Rate: 226.0
Qualification Code: P

---------------------
|  Sample Summary   |
---------------------
### USGS - 13206000 ###
Timestamp: Thu 30 Dec 2021 09:30:00 PM UTC
Flow Rate: 226.0
```

I need to be able to use another constructor class called FlowSample that takes in a single String value as a parameter

```
public FlowSample(String line) {...}
```

I have created one FlowSample constructor:

```
public FlowSample(String agency, String siteNumber, String timeZone, String qualCode, String timestamp, double flowRate) 
    {
        this.agency = agency;
        this.siteNumber = siteNumber;
        this.qualCode = qualCode;
        this.flowRate = flowRate;

        /* Create date formatter and parse */
        // 2021-12-20 14:30
        SimpleDateFormat myFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm");  // Format is same as data from USGS data

        // Creating new timezone method and passes TimeZone object into myFormatter
        myFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));

        try 
        {
            // passing in timestamp from constructor
            this.timestamp = myFormatter.parse(timestamp);
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Unable to parse timestamp: " + timestamp);
            /* Initialize timestamp with the epoch, January 1, 1970, 00:00:000 GMT */
            this.timestamp = new Date(0);
        }
    }
```

I am unsure how to use the delimiter to print the data like this and I need help. Does anyone know how to help me and how the constructor should look and how to call it?

Comment: First suggestion: Do not use `SimpleDateFormat`. Instead use the modern [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Second suggestion: "_how to use the delimiter_" Not 100% sure what you mean... But to include a tab in a Java `String` use `\t` as in `"foo\tbar"`

Comment: `MST` is not a [real time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Time zone names are in a format of `Continent/Region` such as `America/Edmonton`. Those 2-4 character pseudo-zones are not standardized, and are not even unique.

Comment: Before posting here, search Stack Overflow thoroughly. Parsing tab-delimited text has been covered many times already. Ditto for parsing date-time text.

Comment: It doesn’t show from the question text, but the input line is equal to a string of `"USGS\t13206000\t2021-12-30 14:30\tMST\t226\tP"`.

Comment: I would use an intermediate step so you get three constructors in all (they need not be public all of them). In your `FlowSample(String line)` constructor simply call `this(line.split("\t"));`. This will pass an array of strings to the next constructor. Declare it as `FlowSample(String[] splitLine)` and implement as `this(splitLine[0], splitLine[1], splitLine[3], splitLine[5], splitLine[2], Double.parseDouble(splitLine[4]));`, which in turn calls the constructor you already have.

Comment: Handling local and UTC timestamp: In `FlowSample` declare `timestamp` a `ZonedDateTime`. To initialize it concatenate timestamp and time zone and parse using `this.timestamp = ZonedDateTime.parse(timestamp + timeZone, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mmz", Locale.ROOT));`. For formatting for output use a `DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a zzz", Locale.US);`. Get your formatted strings from `timestamp.format(fmt)` (local) and `timestamp.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")).format(fmt)` (UTC).

Comment: I also would not initialize the timestamp to epoch in case of a parse error but rather throw an exception. You know your use case and requirements the best, though.

Answer (score 0):

Create some sample data.

```
String input = "USGS\t13206000\t2021-12-30 14:30\tMST\t226\tP";
```

Define a class as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) to represent your flow sample.

```
record FlowSample( String agency , String siteNumber , ZonedDateTime when , int flowRate , String qualityCode ) { }
```

Notice that we use field for our final desired fields. A record’s default constructor directly assigns a value to each field. That is a good thing. You should  keep your constructors as short, simple, and sweet as possible. Parsing should be done *outside* the constructor. So let's add a `static` factory method to mediate between our textual input and our desired object.

Before we can write that factory method, we have to deal with a flaw in your input data. Your input uses `MST` as a time zone. Unfortunately, such 2-4 letter pseudo-zones are not standard. They are not even unique! Does `MST` mean *Malaysia Standard Time*? Or *Mountain Standard Time (North America)*? Even then, those values may refer to any of several multiple real time zones, each zone having its own history of past, present, and future changes to its offset-from-UTC. For example, [Mountain Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_Time_Zone) implies any of several time zones in Canada, United States, and Mexico.

These pseudo-zones should be used only in localized text for presentation to users (if that), and  never used when exchanging date-time values.

So are stuck with two possible ways to address your input-data flaw:

- Convince the publisher of your data to use [real time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) identifiers (`Continent/Region`) rather than these 2-4 character strings.
- Write a method that takes a guess at parsing such inputs.

Let's write that method.

```java
static ZoneId guessAtParsingPseudoTimeZone ( String pseudoZone )
{
    return switch ( pseudoZone )
    {
        case "MST" -> ZoneId.of( "America/Denver" );
        case "PST" -> ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" );
        default -> throw new IllegalStateException( "Unexpected pseudo time zone: " + pseudoZone );
    };
}
```

Now we can complete that `static` parsing method.

Note that we are *not* using the terribly flawed date-time classes seen in the Question. Those legacy classes were years ago supplanted by  the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. A date with time-of-day should be parsed as a `LocalDateTime`. However, a `LocalDateTime` is ambiguous as it cannot represent a point on the timeline. To pinpoint a point on the timeline, we need to apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```java
static FlowSample parse ( String input )
{
    String[] parts = input.split( "\t" );
    String a = parts[ 0 ];
    String s = parts[ 1 ];
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( parts[ 2 ].replace( " " , "T" ) );
    ZoneId z = FlowSample.guessAtParsingPseudoTimeZone( parts[ 3 ] ); // Take a guess as to what the non-standard non-unique pseudo time zone might mean. CAUTION: This is faulty data. You should convince your data publisher to use real time zone names.
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );
    int f = Integer.parseInt( parts[ 4 ] );
    String q = parts[ 5 ];
    return new FlowSample( a , s , zdt , f , q );
}
```

Write a complete example demo app to exercise our `FlowSample` record.

```java
package work.basil.example.parsing;

import java.time.*;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {

        String input = "USGS\t13206000\t2021-12-30 14:30\tMST\t226\tP"; // Agency, Site number, Date-time, Pseudo-time-zone, Flow rate, Quality code.

        record FlowSample( String agency , String siteNumber , ZonedDateTime when , int flowRate , String qualityCode )
        {
            static FlowSample parse ( String input )
            {
                String[] parts = input.split( "\t" );
                String a = parts[ 0 ];
                String s = parts[ 1 ];
                LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( parts[ 2 ].replace( " " , "T" ) );
                ZoneId z = FlowSample.guessAtParsingPseudoTimeZone( parts[ 3 ] ); // Take a guess as to what the non-standard non-unique pseudo time zone might mean. CAUTION: This is faulty data. You should convince your data publisher to use real time zone names.
                ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z );
                int f = Integer.parseInt( parts[ 4 ] );
                String q = parts[ 5 ];
                return new FlowSample( a , s , zdt , f , q );
            }

            static ZoneId guessAtParsingPseudoTimeZone ( String pseudoZone )
            {
                return switch ( pseudoZone )
                {
                    case "MST" -> ZoneId.of( "America/Denver" );
                    case "PST" -> ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" );
                    default -> throw new IllegalStateException( "Unexpected pseudo time zone: " + pseudoZone );
                };
            }
        }

        FlowSample flowSample = FlowSample.parse( input );
        System.out.println( "flowSample = " + flowSample );
    }
}
```

When run.

> flowSample = FlowSample[agency=USGS, siteNumber=13206000, when=2021-12-30T14:30-07:00[America/Denver], flowRate=226, qualityCode=P]

To report that moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero), just call `ZonedDateTime#toInstant`.

```
String utc = flowSample.when().toInstant().toString() ;
```

---

By the way, that `qualityCode` field should likely be a custom-defined enum rather than a mere string. Perhaps also the `agency`. I will leave that as an exercise for the reader.